# The order of conjugate subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

> Let $G$ be a group, and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

Then, for any fixed $g\in G$, i know that $H\cong gHg^{-1}$ by inner-automorphism.

I have some question about the 'order':

(1) Is it true that $|H|=|gHg^{-1}|$ if $|H|<\infty$ or $|G:H|<\infty$?

(2) If (1) is true, give some counterexample for the case that $|H|=\infty$ or $|G:H|=\infty$.

Thank you!

Comment: It’s true that $|H|=|gHg^{-1}|$ **always**. Isomorphisms require a bijective underlying function, and a bijection establishes equality of cardinality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three facts needed, here:

- Every group isomorphism is a bijection.
- Given two sets $A$ and $B,$ $A$ and $B$ are of equal cardinality if and only if there exists a bijection between them.
- The order of a group is the cardinality of the set of its elements.

Consequently, we will always have $|H|=\left|gHg^{-1}\right|.$